# Notepad++ Remove line have string length than 10 character

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

Notepad++ can remove line less than 10 character.

```
^.{0,9}$
```

But, if i want remove line have string length than 10 character?

Example:.

```
hello world, my name Peter.
hello world, mynamePeter.
```

The string "mynamePeter" have over 10 character, i need remove line container "mynamePeter". How i can do it?

Comment: Not sure whether it works or not but you can use ^.{10,}$ to match lines with more than 10 characters.

Comment: Your question is not clear, I think you're making a mixed between string and word. Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59014281/edit) and add expected result. Do you want to remove the whole line or only the words with length greater than (or equal?) 10 characters?

Comment: I have update question to clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*?\b\w{10,}\b*?(?:\R|\z)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  .*?               # 0 or more any character but newline
  \b                # word boundary
  \w{10,}           # 10 or more word character
  \b                # word boundary
  .*?               # 0 or more any character but newline
  (?:\R|\z)         # non capture group, end of line or end of file
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `.{10,}\r?\n` for line longer any 10 char.

Or if word with 10 or more: `.*\w{10}.*\r?\n`